# Using Fiona to write a new shapefile from scratch

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, epsg, fiona

I am new to Fiona, and trying to wrap my head around reading a csv file and writing out an ESRI shapefile.  I have most of it down, but am missing two things; (1) defining the projection/spatial reference and (2) the attributes actually being populated with the values from the csv file.

So my questions are:
1. How do I define the spatial reference, either by defining an EPSG or a custom projection
2. Why is my data not writing as attributes?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```py
import csv
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping
from fiona import collection
from fiona.crs import from_epsg


schema = { 'geometry': 'Point', 
 'properties': {'dx': 'float:13.3',
            'dy': 'float:13.3',
            'dline': 'str',
            'dtrace': 'int',
            'ddepth': 'float:9.4',
            'dtrash': 'float:9.4',               
            'sx': 'float:13.3',
            'sy': 'float:13.3',
            'sline': 'str',
            'strace': 'int',
            'sdepth': 'float:9.4',
            'strash': 'float:9.4',                 
            'bx': 'float:13.3',
            'by': 'float:13.3',
            'bline': 'str',
            'btrace': 'int',
            'bdepth': 'float:9.4',
            'btrash': 'float:9.4',}}

with collection(
shapeout, "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema) as output:
with open(finalout, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        point = Point(float(row['dx']), float(row['dy']))
        output.write({
            'properties': {'dx': 'float:13.3',
            'dy': 'float:13.3',
            'dline': 'str',
            'dtrace': 'int',
            'ddepth': 'float:9.4',
            'dtrash': 'float:9.4',               
            'sx': 'float:13.3',
            'sy': 'float:13.3',
            'sline': 'str',
            'strace': 'int',
            'sdepth': 'float:9.4',
            'strash': 'float:9.4',                 
            'bx': 'float:13.3',
            'by': 'float:13.3',
            'bline': 'str',
            'btrace': 'int',
            'bdepth': 'float:9.4',
            'btrash': 'float:9.4',},
            'geometry': mapping(point)
        })
```

With the code updated to the "newer" (aka, not outdated) process:

```
with fiona.open(shapeout, 'w', crs=from_epsg(3996), driver='ESRI Shapefile', 
            schema=myschema) as output:
with open(finalout, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        #geometry
        point = Point(float(row['dx']), float(row['dy']))
        #attributes
        prop = {'dx': float(row['dx']),
                'dy': float(row['dy']),
                'dline': str(row['dline']),
                'dtrace': float(row['dtrace']),                    
                'ddepth': float(row['ddepth']),                    
                'dtrash': float(row['dtrash'])}, 
        print{'geometry': mapping(point), 'properties':prop}
```

Gives me this:

```
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (-245215.3333, -975226.3333)}, 'properties': ({'dtrace': 24387.0, 'ddepth': 1433.2458, 'dtrash': 1433.25, 'dx': -245215.3333, 'dy': -975226.3333, 'dline': '      lsl0904.201302'},)}
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (-245215.0, -975251.0)}, 'properties': ({'dtrace': 24386.0, 'ddepth': 1432.7268, 'dtrash': 1432.73, 'dx': -245215.0, 'dy': -975251.0, 'dline': '      lsl0904.201302'},)}
```

But as soon as I change to:

```
output.write({'geometry': mapping(point), 'properties':prop})
```

I get the error message:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 19):

Your solution is a little out of date (look at [Fiona - Preffered method for defining a schema](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74858/fiona-preffered-method-for-defining-a-schema/74866#74866)). For a better solution  look at that proposed by Sean Gillies in [gistfile1.py](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/5937555) to parse a delimited text file  data and create a new shapefile

#### 1) How do I define the spatial reference: [Fiona crs Module](http://toblerity.org/fiona/fiona.html#module-fiona.crs)

```py
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
from_epsg(3857)
{'init': 'epsg:3857', 'no_defs': True}
```

So, to write a new shapefile (not need of `collection`):

```py
with fiona.open('your_shapefile.shp', 'w',crs=from_epsg(3857),driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=yourschema) as output:
```

C2) Why is my data not writing as attributes?

In you script, you are confusing the schema of the shapefile and the attributes:

- Definition of the geometry type and the fields of a shapefile = schema of the layer

```py
 yourschema =  {'geometry': 'Point',
               'properties': {'bx': 'float:13.3',
                'by': 'float:13.3',
                'bline': 'str',
                'btrace': 'int',
                'bdepth': 'float:9.4',
                'btrash': 'float:9.4'}}
```

- values from the dx field in the table:

```py
for row in reader:
     # the value is
        dx = float(row['dx']
        ....
```

You script becomes: (you must use the `mapping`function of shapely and not `shape` (opposite)):

```py
with fiona.open(shapeout, 'w',crs=from_epsg(3857),driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=yourschema) as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(finalout)
    for row in reader:
          # geometry
          point = Point(float(row['dx']), float(row['dy']))
          # attributes
          prop = {'dx': float(row['dx']),'dy': float(row['dy']),....,'btrash': float(row['btrash')}
          # write the row (geometry + attributes in GeoJSON format)
          output.write({'geometry': mapping(point), 'properties':prop})
```

explication of `shape`and `mapping`:

```py
shape(point)
<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x105ebb450>
# GeoJSON format
mapping(point)
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (..., ...)}
```

#### New

You can test the solution: I use here one of my files as an example:

```py
from csv import DictReader
reader = DictReader(open("test.csv"), delimiter=',')
elem = reader.next()
print elem.keys()
['Y', 'X', 'Type', 'dip', 'dip_direct']
print elem.values()
['93729.059941647559754', '255598.788501376315253', 'N', '37', '340']
```

So a simple schema is (without [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)):

```py
schema={
  'geometry': 'Point', 
  'properties': {
      'X':'float',
      'Y': 'float',
      'Type': 'str:10', 
      'dip': 'int', 
      'dip_direct': 'int'}}
```

and for testing only the GeoJSON result (without creating the shapefile):

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping
reader = DictReader(open("test.csv"), delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
     point = Point(float(row['X']), float(row['Y']))
     prop = {'X': float(row['X']), 'Y' :float(row['Y']),'Type':row['Type'],'dip':int(row['dip']),'dip_direct':int(row['dip_direct'])}
     print {'geometry':mapping(point),'properties': prop}
 {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (255598.78850137632, 93729.05994164756)}, 'properties': {'Y': 93729.05994164756, 'X': 255598.78850137632, 'Type': 'N', 'dip': 37, 'dip_direct': 340}}
 {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (255493.10748570191, 93839.054468165821)}, 'properties': {'Y': 93839.054468165821, 'X': 255493.10748570191, 'Type': 'N', 'dip': 20, 'dip_direct': 330}}
```

#### New

First, I don't know if that was a mistake but the indentation is not correct:

```py
with fiona.open(shapeout...:
    with open(finalout, 'rb') as f:
       reader = csv.DictReader(f)
```

If you use `csv.DictReader`, you don't need  `with open(finalout, 'rb') as f:`.

```py
 with fiona.open(shapeout...:
    reader = csv.DictReader(finalout)
```

With my example:

```py
with fiona.open('my_shapefile.shp', 'w',crs=from_epsg(3857),driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=schema) as output:
    reader = DictReader(open("test.csv"), delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
         point = Point(float(row['X']), float(row['Y']))
         prop = {'X': float(row['X']), 'Y' :float(row['Y']),'Type':row['Type'],'dip':int(row['dip']),'dip_direct':int(row['dip_direct'])}
         output.write({'geometry':mapping(point),'properties': prop})
```

Test:

```py
c = fiona.open('my_shapefile.shp')
# schema of the shapefile
c.schema
{'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'Y', 'float'), (u'X', 'float'), (u'Type', 'str:10'), (u'dip', 'int:10'), (u'dip_direct', 'int:10')])}
# crs of the shapefile
c.crs
{u'a': 6378137, u'lon_0': 0, u'no_defs': True, u'y_0': 0, u'b': 6378137, u'proj': u'merc', u'x_0': 0, u'units': u'm', u'lat_ts': 0}
# first row of the shapefile
c.next()
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (255598.78850137632, 93729.05994164756)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'Y', 93729.05994164756), (u'X', 255598.78850137632), (u'Type', u'N'), (u'dip', 37), (u'dip_direct', 340)])}
```

Comment: Gene - many thanks, especially the explanation of the epsg operation.  I have implemented these changes, but am getting an error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: look at my example

Comment: Gene- yes, that follows perfectly what my code does when I      print{'geometry': mapping(point), 'properties':prop}, but the attempt to write to shapefile causes the error.  Sorry, I am sure the problem is quite clear to you, I am just missing it.  I had a colleague look at it also, and he is just as confused as I am.

Comment: You have a problem with your script: you do not need to open twice your csv file (see above)