# Creating point shapefile from Excel with Fiona

Tags: python, fiona

I am attempting to use fiona and xlrd to convert a complicated excel spreadsheet to a shapefile (point).  I am trying to figure out how, during the `.write` call, to send the list of coordinates I've pulled out of the spreadsheet and use them to draw the geometry.  Here's an abbreviation of what I've got so far:

```
shapefile_dir = r'C:\Temp'
point_shapefile = os.path.join(shapefile_dir, '{}_export_p.shp'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m')))

schema_properties = {
    'guid': 'str:50'
    'dateTime': 'str:16'
}

point_schema = {'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': schema_properties}

with fiona.open(point_shapefile, 'w', crs=from_epsg(4326), driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=point_schema) as layer:
    with xlrd.open_workbook(wkbk) as wb:
        cs = wb.sheet_by_name('Master')
        keys = [cs.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(cs.ncols)]
        dict_list = []
        for row_index in xrange(1, cs.nrows):
            d = {keys[col_index]: cs.cell(row_index, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(cs.ncols)}
            dict_list.append(d)

        for idict in dict_list:
            try:
                guid = idict['A']
                dateTime = idict['DATE']
                declat = idict['DECLAT']
                declon = idict['DECLON']
                try:
                    layer.write({'geometry': (declat, declon), 'properties': {
                        'guid': guid,
                        'dateTime': dateTime
                except: #except clause for writing the geometry and attributes
            except: #except clause for getting values out of dictionary list
```

I'm a little overboard with xlrd because I need this to scale to read a workbook with *n* number of sheets.

But currently I'm getting an error

```
tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Which of course means I'm missing something very basic.

My values are being fetched from the excel spreadsheet correctly, so I think I'm almost there.  But I'm not sure I'm thinking through this procedure correctly.  Should I be stashing the `xlrd` operations inside of the `fiona` write loop?  How do I get from that list of XYs, cast them to `float` and then write them as a new row in the shapefile?

I reviewed [Fiona - Preffered method for defining a schema](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74858/fiona-preffered-method-for-defining-a-schema)

but I guess I'm not clear on how to adapt some of the methods in there to my own data.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually doing conversion from UTM to get the decimal degree notation, and didn't include it for sake of brevity.  I still end up with good coords in `declat` and `declon` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiona uses the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format and `layer.write({'geometry': (declat, declon), ...` is not correct

Why ?

```
declon= 5 # integer or float and not string !
declat = 50  # integer or float and not string !
geom = ({'geometry': (declat, declon)})
print geom
{'geometry': (50, 5)}
```

The GeoJSON format uses `Point(longitude, latitude)` (`Point(x,y)` and not `Point(y,x)`).

The correct formulation is

```
geom = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (declon, declat)} # Point(x,y)
print geom
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (5, 50)}
```

Therefore

```
geom = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (declon, declat)}
prop = {'guid': guid,'dateTime': dateTime}
output.write({'geometry':geom, 'properties': prop})
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the excellent explanation @gene!